# Bluetooth mouse has jittery polling rate

Tags: 18.04, mouse, bluetooth

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and my Logitech MX Master connected via bluetooth has recently started to become very jittery. Here is an excerpt from the output of evhz: (https://gitlab.com/iankelling/evhz)

```
MX Master: Latest  1000Hz, Average   483Hz
ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer: Latest    11Hz, Average    13Hz
MX Master: Latest    20Hz, Average   496Hz
MX Master: Latest  1000Hz, Average   485Hz
ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer: Latest    13Hz, Average    13Hz
MX Master: Latest    20Hz, Average   497Hz
MX Master: Latest  1000Hz, Average   486Hz
MX Master: Latest    20Hz, Average   498Hz
MX Master: Latest  1000Hz, Average   487Hz
ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer: Latest    13Hz, Average    13Hz
MX Master: Latest    20Hz, Average   498Hz
MX Master: Latest  1000Hz, Average   488Hz
ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer: Latest    13Hz, Average    13Hz
MX Master: Latest    20Hz, Average   499Hz
MX Master: Latest  1000Hz, Average   489Hz
MX Master: Latest    20Hz, Average   499Hz
MX Master: Latest  1000Hz, Average   490Hz
```

`cat /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/mousepoll` outputs 0, so I've tried forcing a polling rate in `/etc/modules` as such:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

-r usbhid
usbhid mousepoll=2
```

It seems that I've done that wrong, as `cat /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/mousepoll` still just outputs 0. Does anyone have a suggestion what I could try next? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Removing the `usbhid` module does not disable my mouse, so it does not affect bluetooth.  Some threads ([1](https://old.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/cim3oc/bluetooth_mouse_polling_rate_somehow_dropped_to/), [2](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=248133)) mention that setting `/sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval`, `conn_min_interval` and `conn_latency` should work, but they do not for me. Setting the same parameters via `hcitool` does work. Connect the mouse, and obtain the handle from the bluetooth connection with hcitool:

```
# hcitool -i hci0 con
Connections:
    < LE 12:34:56:78:9A:BC handle 3585 state 1 lm MASTER AUTH ENCRYPT
```

Then set low values for min, max and latency as above:

```
hcitool lecup --handle 3585 --min=6 --max=7 --latency=0
```

hcitool notes the factor for min and max is 1.25ms, so this should accept polling rates with an interval of 7.5ms - 8.75ms.

As the settings only apply to the bluetooth connection, the solution immediately stops working after the mouse disconnects, so if anyone has a more permanent solution I would love to hear about it!

Comment: Have you found a more permanent solution in the meantime? I have the same issue since a recent update last week.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I bound the above workaround to a keybind so I can press it every time the mouse connects. In the end I ended up just buying a unifying receiver :/